# How to make telegram snap use home folder by default

Tags: 16.10, snap, telegram

I have installed telegram snap and files are saving in `~/snap/telegram-desktop`, or when i want to send a file, the file browser dialog shows this directory by default which is a bit annoying.
Is there any way to disable this sandbox mode and save files in `~/Downloads` directory and when display the home folder when trying to send a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telegram has an option to set where downloads go. Open settings and under "Don't ask download path for each file", next to "Download path:" there is a link titled "default folder". Click that.

[image: Chat Settings]

In the following popup titled "Choose download path". Select "Custom folder, cleared only manually", then select your `/home/user/Downloads` folder from the next file selection dialog, then click 'Save'.

[image: Choose download path]

Comment: Thanks, fixed my problem, but is there a way to avoid sandboxing for snap packages?

Comment: Not in a way I would recommend